# After accessing static methods in static inner classes from main class in java, eclipse is giving warning

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, inner-classes, static-classes

I have a class -->

```
    public class Machine
```

There I have declared a static inner class -->

```
   public static class Parts
```

Inside static inner class I have declared two static methods -->

```
    public static void engine()
    public static void battery()
```

Now I want to access the methods from my main class App. I am using Eclipse IDE. I did -

```
    Machine.Parts machine = new Machine.Parts();
    machine.engine();
    machine.battery();
```

Eclipse is letting me to do it. But it is giving me warning -
*The static method engine from the type Machine.Parts should be accessed in a static way*
*The static method engine from the type Machine.Parts should be accessed in a static way*

How to resolve this problem?

I have tried google search and stack overflow previous questions. But nowhere I could find the solution.

My code -

Machine.java -->

```
package demo28;

public class Machine {

    public static class Parts {
        public static void engine() {
            System.out.println("Machine engine is running");
        }
        public static void battery() {
            System.out.println("Machine battery is charging");
        }
    }
}
```

App.java -->

```
package demo28;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        run(new Machine.Parts());
    }

    public static void run(Machine.Parts machine) {
        machine.engine();
        machine.battery();
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Output -->


    *Machine engine is running

    Machine battery is charging*

Expected --> No warning

Actual --> Getting warning

Comment: Accessing in a static way is e.g : `Machine.Parts.engine()` (you call the method directly on the class, not on an instance of the class) .

Comment: first of all, a warning is not an error. secondly: read the warning. If you know what 'static' means, the meaning of that warning should be clear to you

Comment: Static methods do not require instantiating a new object. So calling `Machine.Parts.engine()` would be the normal way of accessing them, though not necessary. The warning is simply meant to cause you to review your design as you're currently using your code in a "non-standard" way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
 Machine.Parts machine = new Machine.Parts();
```

You are creating an **instance** of that inner class. Then you go:

```
 machine.engine();
```

... invoking a **static** method, as if it were a non-static method of that class.

Yes, the above code works, but it is bad practice. If you meant to have "real" non-static methods, simply drop that keyword from the method signatures. Otherwise, change your code to:

```
Machine.Parts.engine();
```

Because that is what **really** happens in your code example.